# How to define configs multiple endpoints for a WCF self-hosted service?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, endpoint, wcf-web-api, wcftestclient

I have two WCF Web API Contracts. Before this, I was happy that I could use TestClient. But after I implemented the second one I had to define endpoints (and could not use the default one) and after that, either I see nothing in browser or this message saying that "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it." when I try to go to the endpoint address. It is the same when I try the config file (although I do not know how to set "EnableTestClient = true"). I really appreciate any help.

```
        var baseurl = new Uri("http://localhost:7000/api/v1.0");
        var config = new HttpConfiguration() { EnableTestClient = true };
        config.CreateInstance = (type, context, request) => container.Resolve(type);
        var host = new HttpServiceHost(typeof(ServiceAPI), config, baseurl);

        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(
            new ServiceMetadataBehavior() { HttpGetEnabled = true, HttpGetUrl = baseurl });            

        // Add MEX endpoint
        //host.AddServiceEndpoint(
        //  ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
        //  MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
        //  "mex"
        //);

        //host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IStatAPI), new WebHttpBinding(), "/stat");
        //host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IAlarmAPI), new WebHttpBinding(), "/alarm");            

        host.Faulted += (s, e) => Debug.WriteLine(e);            

        host.Open();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that multiple endpoints should be used to expose different APIs. They are for exposing the same contract with a different binding. 
You should create a new host for each API.  You can share the config between them though.